# forcing first char of strings to be returned on myString[1] instead of myString[0]?

Tags: c++, string

I'd like string representations in my code to start with index 1 (not 0). The paper I'm working from indexes at 1; I'd like to remain consistent with the original description.

At the moment I'm simply initialising strings with an additional space char:

```
the_string = ' ' + string;
```

However, it means `the_string.length()` is inconsistent with the 'real' length of the string.

Which alternative workaround (write my own string indexing function, make a mystring class and overload the []operator etc.) generates the least code and what is it?

Comment: Bad solution is to use a macro to reduce the index. e.g. `the_string[I(1)]` will refer to index 0, with `#define I(x) (x-1)`

Comment: You could use an index function taking a string and a 1-based index.

Comment: I'm OK with bad in this case. I'm really interested in the most concise solution!

Comment: You could do something novel and generalize the concept to 0-index-based strings.  You know, like the rest of the world.

Comment: @keith.layne I plan to. It's just working out easier for debugging etc. at the moment if I follow the paper exactly.

Comment: Oh for the love of god why! You are the sort of person who makes life so much harder

Comment: This is going to be *extremely* confusing for anyone reading your code. Not recommended.

Comment: It's not extremely confusing for me.

Comment: It will be once you get used to how arrays work in C/C++.

Comment: This makes my life easier until I've implemented the algorithm, closely following the existing paper and nomenclature. Then it's a simple case of implementing a less 'confusing' solution.

Comment: I understand how arrays work in C/C++

Comment: I don't think this is *that* evil if the workflow is: #1 directly transcribe the algorithm from the paper, to avoid introducing any transcription bugs; #2 write tests, run them, fix any bugs (hopefully none) until the tests pass; #3 Remove hack used for direct transcription and go back to 0-based indexing; #4 make sure tests still pass, and no bugs were introduced by the conversion to 0-based indexing. I think of it as scaffolding, basically.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes yes that is exactly what I'm doing. quite surprised at all the hate I'm getting :-)

Comment: @nhahtdh feel free to make your comment into an actual answer which I'll accept. It works, I'm using it as a temporary hack and I doubt it could be any more concise. thanks.

Comment: I've gotta +1 this :p While I don't think it's a good idea it's not a stupid question either.  Sometimes the solution to a question is just "Don't do it" though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short and bad solution is to use a macro expansion to -1 the index.

```
#define I(x) ((x) - 1)

the_string[I(1)] // This will access the first character of the string.
```

This is fine if you want to align your solution on paper and code - but never let that code get into any production system.

Comment: What the hell? was the idea not that he wanted to be able to seamlessly use 'one' based indexing for strings, and this solution is making it painfully obvious that he is not doing that. It is also now dependent on NEVER forgetting to wrap your index in the decrement macro, and I can grantee, it will happen soon enough

Comment: @thecoshman: The OP wants something that works and generates the least code. This is probably why he accepts this answer. Better solution is that of `infact`'s.

Comment: in that case, why not just type '-1' where ever he uses his index, it's 'less code'; you'r solution is actually 50% more code then that simple alternative I just suggested. Not to mention it avoids the few dozen characters it takes to set up your solution

Comment: @thecoshman because the convention of indexing at 1 is ubiquitous throughout the entire algorithm for looping, graph traversal, labelling leaf nodes and labelling edges and not only for the indexing of chars in strings. for more details: http://www.stanford.edu/~mjkay/gusfield.pdf

Comment: @thecoshman: There is a con when you use `-1`. When the index is mixed with some calculation, then it will be confusing what the `-1` is doing (one example is accessing the last element in the array).

Comment: "in that case, why not just type -1" how would you propose to distinguish between "-1"s that are related to the algorithm's indexing and "-1"s that are purely related to the implementation? it is an inferior workaround.